# How can I get the results of a Sunspot Searchable code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

So I have a Model with a 'searchable' block defining everything just fine. Model.Search is also working as expected.
My goal is to get the data from the 'searchable' block as a json for a specific Model instance:

For example:

```
class Model
  searchable do
    integer :id
    name :string
  end
end
```

And I would like to get:
{id: 123, name: 'my name'}

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this http://rahil.ca/blog/how-to-set-up-a-rails-search-api-with-json-and-sunspot-solr/#json-api